# Random values when retrieving jint value using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am passing a java object of type 'Properties' to c++ using JNI.

I retrieve an int value that is inserted into the Properties object using the following statements.

```
int intVal = 1;
Properties propObj = new Properties();
propObj.put("KEY_FOR_INT", intVal);
```

When i try to retrieve the value in c++ using JNI with the following statement, i get random values.

```
jint intValueFromJava = env->CallIntMethod(propObj, propGetID, env->NewStringUTF("KEY_FOR_INT"));
```

If i try to retrieve a string value or ArrayList, i am able to get it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try to see if an exception occurred after the call

```
jint intValueFromJava = env->CallIntMethod(propObj, propGetID, env->NewStringUTF("KEY_FOR_INT"));
jthrowable exc = env->ExceptionOccurred();
```

It is possible that the method you are calling returns an Object rather then an int, if it is

```
public synchronized V get(Object key);
```

Didn't work for a while with jni but it possible that unboxing does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it working by adding Object of type Integer in the Properties object and parsed the value using the intValue method of Integer class. Here is the code i used.

java:

```
int intVal = 1;
Properties propObj = new Properties();
propObj.put("KEY_FOR_INT", new Integer(intVal));
```

c++:

```
jobject intObjVal = env->CallObjectMethod(propObj, propGetID, env->NewStringUTF("KEY_FOR_INT"));
jint intVal = env->CallIntMethod(intObjVal, intValueID);
int myRequiredVal = (int)intVal;
```

Comment: The first part was already happening automatically via autoboxing. Doing it yourself didn't change anything.